# WCF Serialization and Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization

i am new to WCF Service. I am creating WCF Service which take record from Dynamics CRM. After deployed to IIS, i tested the service. And the service run well when and returning data with xml format. Here's is my code

**Service.svc**

```
public List<Presid> GetPresalesIdList(string userlogin)
    {
        List<Presid> idsales = new List<Presid>();
        Presid presales = new Presid();
        string cmb = userdomain + userlogin;
        InitializeCRMService(userName, passWord, domain);

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userlogin))
            {
                QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression("systemuser");
                string[] cols = { "businessunitid", "domainname", "systemuserid" };
                qe.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
                qe.Criteria.AddCondition("domainname", ConditionOperator.Equal, cmb);
                qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(cols);

                var guid = _service.RetrieveMultiple(qe);

                userid = ((EntityReference)guid[0].Attributes["businessunitid"]).Id;
                systemid = (Guid)guid[0].Attributes["systemuserid"];


                QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("opportunity");
                string[] cols2 = { "new_presalesid","createdon", "ownerid", "name", "parentaccountid", "statecode", "estimatedclosedate" };
                query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
                query.Criteria.AddCondition("ownerid", ConditionOperator.Equal, systemid);
                query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(cols2);
                EntityCollection preid = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

                string prsId = string.Empty;
                string optNm = string.Empty;
                string cusNm = string.Empty;
                string stscde = string.Empty;
                DateTime closedate;
                DateTime open;


                foreach (Entity enty in preid.Entities)
                {

                    presales = new Presid();
                    if (enty.Attributes.Contains("new_presalesid"))
                    {
                        prsId = enty.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_presalesid");
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prsId))
                        {
                            presales.PresalesID = prsId;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            presales.PresalesID = null;
                        }
                    }

                    if (enty.Attributes.Contains("name"))
                    {
                        optNm = enty.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(optNm))
                        {
                            presales.OptiName = optNm;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            presales.OptiName = null;
                        }
                    }

                    //cusNm = enty.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("parentaccountid").Name;

                    if (enty.Attributes.Contains("parentaccountid"))
                    {
                        cusNm = ((EntityReference)enty["parentaccountid"]).Name;

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cusNm))
                        {
                            presales.CustomerName = cusNm;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            presales.CustomerName = null;
                        }
                    }

                    if (enty.Attributes.Contains("statecode"))
                    {
                        stscde = enty.FormattedValues["statecode"];
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stscde))
                        {
                            presales.Status = stscde;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            presales.Status = null;
                        }
                    }


                    if (enty.Attributes.Contains("estimatedclosedate"))
                    {
                        closedate = enty.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("estimatedclosedate");
                        if (closedate != null)
                        {
                            presales.ClosedDate = closedate;
                        }

                    }

                    if (enty.Attributes.Contains("createdon"))
                    {
                        open = enty.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("createdon");
                        if (open != null)
                        {
                            presales.CreateOn = open;
                        }
                    }

                    idsales.Add(presales);
                }
                return idsales;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return idsales;
    }
```

**Presid Class:**

```
namespace WCF_CRM_Multipolar 
{
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://mlpt-web.com/CRM/services")]
public class Presid
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PresalesID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string OptiName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string CustomerName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Status
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<DateTime> ClosedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    [DataMember]
    public DateTime CreateOn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


}
```

}

**IService**

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
      RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
      UriTemplate = "/GetPresalesIdList/{userlogin}")]
    List<Presid> GetPresalesIdList(string userlogin);
```

Those code run well when i tested from my pc by calling from this URL:

```
http://localhost:8076/Service1.svc/Getpresalesidlist/user
```

But, when other division want to call this service by Deserialize it, they say that they can't do it. So they ask me to search what causes the problems. I think that my code is yet serialize, so they are unable to deserialize. Based on that story, i've got questions:

1. Is that true that my code is serialize yet ? If that's true, how to make it serializeable ? 
   I have looking for the example of serializable on the internet. Using something called `MemoryStream`. But i'am unable to implement that within my code. So please show me the way to make my code serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your configuration and your formal declaration, your `List<Presid>` will be in xml format in the response. Perhaps the response is empty {} or an error occurs in which case plain html may be returned to the caller, the error description, depending on server configuration.

One thing to try is to remove the `[Serializable]` attribute as the `[DataContract(Namespace = "http://mlpt-web.com/CRM/services")]` will handle serialization more specific to your configuration. You don't need both.

Comment: Hi @Ross Bush , when i run the service, its returning the data in xml format. Is my code is deserializeable ? If yes, then the problem on the method to deserialize it.

Comment: I update answer. You don't need to use the [Serializable] attribute above.

Comment: so i just need to remove `[Serializable]` ? Oke i'll try. I will inform you after i tried it. Another question, for each class inside WCF, should i use the same namespace  for all class or use different namespace for each class ?

Comment: Either way is fine. You can put all your classes in a few namespaces, one or many.

Comment: do you have an article about consume and deserialize wcf service in webform application or console applcation? I want to try deserialize this WCF and display the result in the webfrom or console. I find it hard for me just to deserialize the service.

Comment: Or you can show me snippet code to deserialize this service

Comment: I am not following. You are wanting to send over your results as a serialized string representation of an PresID, that is what the xml is, it's your PresID serialized as xml?